# How to integrate audio with video?

Tags: c#, audio, video, webcam, aforge

I am capturing images from WebCam and making a video using those images. I am doing all this through [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/). Unfortunately [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) don't support audio. What is the best way to integrate audio with the video. I am creating video in WMV format.

I have two approaches in mind. I can record audio using microphone.

1) I can create a video separately and then somehow integrate captured audio with it.

2) I can integrate audio while creating the video from the images.

Problem is I don't know how I would implement either of these options.

Any ideas? or is there any better approach to achieve it?

Comment: Instead of using AForge I shifted to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24601

Comment: A sample project records both video and audio in single file  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34663/DirectShow-Examples-for-Using-SampleGrabber-for-Gr